# Web Scrape - Scrape Fields with Same Tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I get to a page where there are many rows of data per page.

My code gets to each row, and I am able to scrape the title of each row.

However, all the data after that, all looks to have the same tag names (for example the *author* and *program number* etc)

Based on this, how do I scrape all the data within each row.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
baseURL = 'https://index.mirasmart.com/aan2022/'
for x in range (1,3):
    driver.get(f'https://index.mirasmart.com/aan2022/SearchResults.php?pg={x}')
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
    eachRow=soup.find_all('div',class_='full search-result')
    for item in eachRow:
        title=item.find('h2').text
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :-soup-contains to target by text

```
for result in soup.select('.detail'):
    
    print('title: ', result.find_previous('h2').text)
    
    for item in ['Author:', 'Session Name:', 'Author Disclosures:', 'Topic:', 'Program Number:', 'Author Institution:']:
        try:
            print(item, result.select_one(f'.cell:-soup-contains("{item}")').find_next('span').text)
        except:
            print(f'{item} not found')
    print()
```